# Why don't SAC implementations use state value function?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-learning, deep-rl, soft-actor-critic

When I read [SAC paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.01290), they use state value function $V_\psi(s_t)$ and as do [their implementation](https://github.com/haarnoja/sac). But in other SAC implementations like [stable-baseline3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3), [pytorch-soft-actor-critic](https://github.com/pranz24/pytorch-soft-actor-critic), it seems that they don't use seperate state value function. So, I wondered they are improved version than the original paper?

Comment: For people that aren't so familiar with the details of a "stable value function", can you briefly describe what it is?

Comment: Most implementations follow [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.05905) instead. They concluded that the state-value function is not necessary, making the implementation faster (as we have one network less to train)

Comment: @matorbi Thank you for your comment.